# Checkpoint file not found, restoring evaluation graph

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-ml

I have a model which runs in a distributed mode for 4000 steps. After every 120s the accuracies are calculated (as is done in the provided examples). However, at times the last checkpoint file is not found.

Error:

> Couldn't match files for checkpoint gs://path-on-gcs/train/model.ckpt-1485

The checkpoint file is present at the location. A local run for 2000 steps runs perfectly.

```
last_checkpoint = tf.train.latest_checkpoint(train_dir(FLAGS.output_path))
```

I assume that the checkpoint is still in saving process, and the files are not actually written. Tried introducing a wait before the accuracies are calculated as such. However, this seemed to work at first, the model still failed with a similar issue.

```
saver.save(session, sv.save_path, global_step)
time.sleep(2) #wait for gcs to be updated
```

Comment: Is your GCS bucket a regional bucket or a multi regional bucket? You want to use a regional bucket(see [here](https://cloud.google.com/ml/docs/concepts/environment-overview#bucket_region)) because GCS has stronger consistency guarantees for regional buckets then multi-regional buckets. Cloud ML's [getting started guide](https://cloud.google.com/ml/docs/how-tos/getting-set-up#setting_up_your_cloud_storage_bucket) has instructions for creating a regional bucket.

Comment: I had a similar problem : what is inside the checkpoint file ? The checkpoint is a text file that refers to model files. In my case, the distributed sample was using "--write_to_tmp 1" as an option by default, and it ended with inconsistent "gs://path/to/checkpoint".  Within the text file temporary files where referred to because of the option. I added "--write_to_tmp 0" and it solved my problem.

Comment: @Jeremy Lewi: It is a multi-regional bucket.

Comment: @MathiasOrtner: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/blob/master/mnist/hptuning/trainer/task.py#L426 In my case the output_path is the one on gcs, so I presume that a local directory is not created, and model is directly saved onto gcs. However is there a  way in we  can control the way in which these files are written ? Ensuring that the checkpoint file is saved iff the model file which is considerably large ~200MB is completely saved ?

Answer (score 0):

From your comment I think I understand what is going on. I may be wrong.

The cloud_ml distributed sample
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/blob/master/mnist/hptuning/trainer/task.py#L426
uses a temporary file by default. As a consequence, it works locally on the `/tmp`. Once the training is complete, it copies the result on `gs://` but it does not correct the `checkpoint` file which stills contains references to local model files on `/tmp`. Basically, this is a bug.

In order to avoid this, you should launch the training process with `--write_to_tmp 0` or modify the `task.py` file directly for disabling this option. Tensorflow will then directly work on `gs://` and the resulting checkpoint will therefore be consistent. At least it worked for me.

One way of checking if my assumptions are correct is to copy the resulting  `checkpoint` file from `gs://` on your local filesystem using `gsutils` and then output its content.

Comment: The checkpoint file has this : `"model_checkpoint_path: "model.ckpt-1485"` which is the model file it was trying to read before failing. However, in my case the output_path is on the GCS, and it does not create any local dir. Whereas in the above example an argument is read, whose default value is 1, implying the L426 code runs. I am following an earlier version of this file which does not have this argument.

Comment: Ok, nevermind, your problem is not the same than mine was ! Sorry for the noise.

Comment: Thanks for replying, it still helps :). Trying out the training using a regional bucket