# ERROR: Couldn't match files for checkpoint gs://obj-detection/train/model.ckpt

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, tensorboard, google-cloud-ml

I run my detection model on google cloud ml and got this error while running the evaluation script. I found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40189116/checkpoint-file-not-found-restoring-evaluation-graph) that mentioned about this issue, but it seems like the issue's till not be solved. Anyone knows how to fix this? Any helps would be appreciated. Thanks.

> ERROR 2018-02-04 12:53:10 -0600   master-replica-0        Couldn't match files
> for checkpoint gs://obj-detection/train/model.ckpt-0
>
> INFO  2018-02-04 12:53:10 -0600   master-replica-0        No model found in
> gs://obj-detection/train. Will try again in 300 seconds
>
> INFO  2018-02-04 12:58:10 -0600   master-replica-0        Starting evaluation
> at 2018-02-04-18:58:10
>
> ERROR 2018-02-04 12:58:10 -0600   master-replica-0        Couldn't match files
> for checkpoint gs://obj-detection/train/model.ckpt-0
>
> INFO  2018-02-04 12:58:10 -0600   master-replica-0        No model found in
> gs://obj-detection/train. Will try again in 300 seconds
>
> ...

While the training log is working as below:

> ... at somewhere around 14 hours running
>
> INFO  2018-02-04 05:09:05 -0600   worker-replica-3        global step 185874:
> loss = 0.7012 (0.764 sec/step)
>
> INFO  2018-02-04 05:09:05 -0600   worker-replica-4        global step 185873:
> loss = 0.7749 (0.797 sec/step)
>
> INFO  2018-02-04 05:09:05 -0600   worker-replica-2        global step 185875:
> loss = 0.4939 (0.775 sec/step)
>
> INFO  2018-02-04 05:09:05 -0600   master-replica-0        global step 185877:
> loss = 1.1430 (0.850 sec/step)
>
> INFO  2018-02-04 05:09:05 -0600   worker-replica-1        global step 185878:
> loss = 0.8231 (0.777 sec/step)
>
> INFO  2018-02-04 05:09:05 -0600   worker-replica-0        global step 185881:
> loss = 0.6470 (0.779 sec/step)

Comment: Have you tried what was suggested in the first comment on the other case you linked to? "Is your GCS bucket a regional bucket or a multi regional bucket? You want to use a regional bucket(see here) because GCS has stronger consistency guarantees for regional buckets then multi-regional buckets. Cloud ML's getting started guide has instructions for creating a regional bucket."

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yeah, I did create a regional bucket with us-central1 in the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

A few things to check:

1. Is the training code setup to actually export checkpoints? If you're using an `Estimator`, this generally works, assuming you're using the standard methods for running the `Estimator` (e.g., in TF >=1.4, `Estimator.train_and_evaluate`).
2. Are you passing the correct output directory to the code that is saving checkpoints? For instance, could the training code be outputting the checkpoint to a local (temporary?) directory instead of GCS? Could it be saving the checkpoints to a different directory on GCS? A quick scan of the code + some well placed print/logging statements are useful here.
3. How frequently does the training code export checkpoints? e.g., if it saves only 10 minutes, then you would expect about 1-2 "no model found" messages for every successful evaluation.